# imported module and global variables

Tags: python, unit-testing, module

I am trying to write a unit test in python for a code X with function y. In the test code, I use:
from X import y.

However, inside X, there is other functions, function z, that define global variables.
In the test code when function y is imported and then called, it gives this error that these global variables are not defined  (because I especifically only call function y, not z).

Is there a way I can define those needed global variables in my test code and run the imported function (which is "y")?

This is code X:

```
def calc_z:
    global a, b, c
    return(a+b+c)

def calc_y:
    return(a*b*c)
```

I am writing a unit test for calc_y. In the unit test:
from X import calc_y. But calc_y is using those global variables defined in calc_z. I thought I can define global a, b, c in the test file to remove dependency of calc_y on calc_z, but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you please add some code to show the problem, if possible as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I didn't understand your problem from the description .

Comment: Your global variables are not defined in `calc_z`, they are only used there (and the `global` statement is not needed, you can just remove it wirhout changing the outcome). Your variables have to be defined somewhere outside of the functions, otherwise both functions will not work.

Comment: I didn't assign values to variables in the short description here. But in the original code these global values are defined in calc_z.
This module X is not my code and I am only trying to write unit test for some important methods for it.
I guess the general question would be how to write a test for a method when that method uses several variables that are globally defined inside that module?

Comment: Still global variables are not defined inside a function, only referenced, so they must be defined outside of the function, and you should be able to just set them in your test.

Comment: I understand the variables in main are all global, but also those variables inside a function if they are defined global a,b,c those variable become accessible foremother functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to define global variables inside a function, though this is bad programming style (but I understand that you cannot change this). This changes the creation time of the variables (they are usually only created on calling that function), but not the location - they still live globally in the module, and you still can just set them there from outside.

So, a test for your example could look like this (assuming you use pytest):

```py
import x
 
def test_calc_y():
    x.a = 1
    x.b = 2
    x.c = 3
    assert x.calx_y() == 6
```